# Non-writable property returns the new value during assignment, but not after

Tags: javascript

Why does assignment to an unwritable property initially return an updated value?

In the below example, we update an unwritable property. As expected, the value is not actually updated. Strangely, the expression with the assignment operator DOES return an updated value. Why is this? I would expect the assignment operator to return the left-hand side value, which is `obj.foo`'s value.

[MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) on Object.defineProperty, including when property is not writable.

```
let obj = {};

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'foo', {
   value: 'Hello'
};

console.log(obj.foo += ' World!'); // Returns 'Hello World!'

console.log(obj.foo); // Returns 'Hello'
```

Comment: What do you mean by "returns"? How are you viewing the value of the property?

Comment: The value of an assignment expression is the value *assigned*, the right-hand side - in this case, as it's effectively `obj.foo = obj.foo + ' World!'`, that's `'Hello World!'` It doesn't return an updated value of `obj.foo`, because as you observe that value _isn't_ updated.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - ah! I never knew that, I always thought assignment operators returned the left-hand side, not the evaluated value to be assigned. That's wild, thank you.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice - updated the question, I'm just console.logging

Comment: @DonP Are you familiar with the difference between an l-value and an r-value? This is key to understanding why an assignment evaluates to the value being assigned on the right rather than the value of the variable being assigned to on the left.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I haven't heard the term "l-value" vs "r-value" before. Found [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lvalue-and-rvalue-in-c-language/) on google describing L vs R values in C languages. Any other resource you'd suggest? I am very familiar (I think) with memory references vs values in JS.

Comment: @DonP That's basically the idea. When you do `x = y` for example, the `y` on the right means to get the value of the variable named `y` (an r-value), but the `x` on the left means the address of the variable `x` in memory (an l-value). When the assignment is evaluated, the compiler doesn't care about the value of `x` per se. It only cares about the variable's location.